# Deployment to Artifactory Server using Curl

Tags: curl, deployment, artifactory

Using the below command to push the Artifact to the JFrog Artifactory Server

```
curl -v --user username:password -X PUT urlGoesHere --data-binary fileToBeDeployed
```

The thing is that it looks the Artifactory Server been set to use the Secure Password. I used the Encrypted Password and placed in the above command and ran it.

Even after using the secure password, I am getting the error message as below

```
"errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Artifactory configured to accept only encrypted passwords but received a clear text password."
  } ]
```

What am I missing? Any Idea?

Comment: @anandaraja-srinivasan is it possible you used the API Key instead of the encrypted password?

Comment: @drorb Yes. Am using the encrypted password. Even then it's throwing this message. May be curl requires some additional flag to notify the Artifactory that Secure Password is used and  not a Clear Text.

Comment: As far as I know, curl does not need any additional flag for using the secure password (this is not something curl is aware of). You can use curl with the -vv flag and look at the Authorization header and verify that it sends the correct password (notice that it is base64 encoded)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the REST API documentation, there is 3 methods to authentifie a user:

username and raw password (a bad idea):

```
curl -v --user username:rawpassword -X PUT urlGoesHere --data-binary fileToBeDeployed
```

username and api key:

```
curl -v --user username:apikey -X PUT urlGoesHere --data-binary fileToBeDeployed
```

api key only:

```
curl -v -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:apikey" -X PUT urlGoesHere --data-binary fileToBeDeployed
```

**Documentation:**

Rest API (there is some examples with curl):
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

Create an API key: 
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Updating+Your+Profile#UpdatingYourProfile-APIKey